# Intercepting NLog LogInformation/LogWarning/LogError calls

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

Administrators on my web site can list the last X records from a log table. Obviously this is not too efficient if they keep hitting the Browser refresh, when no new records have been logged.

I have implemented caching (I do NOT need help with that). What I need to do is 'intercept' the logging of a record so I can clear an entry from my cache.

Is there a central place to intercept all writes to the log?

ASP.NET Core 3.1, C#, NLog v4.7.5

More details:

I write log records to a database using the ILogger interface.  Each time a log record is written, I need to remove an entry from my cache (I know how to do that bit).  Then the next time someone lists the log they will read the database again and repopulate the cache with the log records.  The cache will then be used for each listing requat until another log record is written, when the cache entry will be cleared again etc.

My question: Is there a centralised location that I can put the code to remove an entry from my cache??

I'm thinking I may need to derive another class from my ILogger and override the LogInformation/LogWarning etc methods, but I thought there may be an neater way.

Comment: Could you please add more details? It's hard to understand what you're looking for.

Comment: Consider using https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MethodCall-target, so when writing to database-target, then also write to methodcall-target that can trigger your cache refresh.

Comment: Added more details.  Also I will investigate Rolf's comment.

Comment: I could not get that to work...

Comment: @RobL Please update your question with the `NLog.config` that fails to call your custom static method using MethodCall-target. Hard to give advice when the response is that it doesn't work. Usually one starts with something simple, like the example from the wiki, and then build from there.

Comment: @RolfKristensen  I'll have a look again tomorrow (late in Aus here).  I'll give it another go and post details here.  Thanks